# Smoke won't collide with my mesh

Tags: smoke-simulation, collision

here's an image:
[image]

Smoke won't collide with my mesh, instead it goes through it. As you can see, my mesh has been given an Effector type: collision. What's the issue here?

Comment: please provide blend file if the answer doesn't help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either try:

- Increasing simulation resolution. (Will increase simulation time.)
- Increase surface thickness on the collider object.